# gridview sorting problem in paging

Tags: asp.net, sorting, gridview

In gridview

when i go to nextpage(page2) and clicked on header to sort, it is sorting all the data. i need to sort only the data in page2

here is my code

```
DataTable dataTable = ViewState["HospAcc"] as DataTable; 
if (dataTable != null) 
{ 
       DataView dv = new DataView(dataTable); 
       dv.Sort = string.Format("{0} {1}", e.SortExpression, Direction); 
       Direction = (Direction == "ASC") ? "DESC" : "ASC"; 
       //Bind resutls 
       gvHospAcc.DataSource = dv; 
       gvHospAcc.DataBind(); 
}
```

and one more thing is when i go to second page my sort is getting collapsed

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

How are you getting your data into the gridview? You could manually page the data that goes into the gridview; that way, when you click on the header, it will only sort the data on that page, since there's no other data besides that.

Comment: DataTable dataTable = ViewState["HospAcc"] as DataTable;
            if (dataTable != null)
            {
                DataView dv = new DataView(dataTable);
                dv.Sort = string.Format("{0} {1}", e.SortExpression, Direction);
                Direction = (Direction == "ASC") ? "DESC" : "ASC";

                //Bind resutls   
                gvHospAcc.DataSource = dv;
                gvHospAcc.DataBind();
            }

Comment: @jestges. u just edit ur question and add this code. It will be more understandable.